# What's the best way of using JSON with iOS apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've recently been looking into the networking aspect of the iOS platform. And I want to incorporate JSON feeds into my application. So I have few questions:

1. What's the best built-in class to parse JSON objects and retrieve them ?
2. When the JSON data is downloaded, how do I store and use it ?

Do I use `NSURL` and `NSURLRequest`?

I'm new to iOS development please help me. Thank You.

Comment: This is likely to be closed due to 1), but for 2) you need to parse the JSON data and store it in the model object(s) you have designed for just that purpose.

Comment: But what's the answer for 1) ?

Comment: You can't ask that here any more as it qualifies for "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: So as a developer with experience (I'm presuming) I am asking you. NSJSONSerialization is not working for me. I've tried it but its just doesn't do the job. Is there any other class I can use ?

Comment: I would find it strange that `NSJSONSerialization` doesn't work - perhaps if you explain what the problem is with that, you might get a response from someone.

Comment: I find it strange as well.  It's not like there is a whole lot of room for interpretation when parsing JSON, hence the class will either do it right or not do it right.  Since thousands of other people use `NSJSONSerialization` with no problem (including myself) I'd guess that there is no problem with it, unless your JSON is so incredibly huge that it can't fit into memory.

Comment: The last paragraph in the answer by @HotLicks is probably the best piece of advice and should be applied to *<insert concept here>*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should probably use NSJSONSerialization, since that's Apple's built-in function.  But there are at least a half-dozen other options -- see json.org for a list.

You have the choice of keeping the JSON as a string and maybe storing it in a file as a string, or parsing it into Objective-C objects (NSArray and NSDictionary), or parsing it and then storing the data therein in a database.  Generally, for short-term use of not terribly large JSON structures, the second option is the way to go.

Do study and understand the JSON syntax at json.org -- it's very simple and takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and you can save yourself a lot of grief.  And understand that NSLog dumps NSArray and NSDictionary objects in a format that strongly resembles JSON, but with `()` for arrays instead of `[]`, and `=` for key/value pairs instead of `:`.

PS:  Please *do not* simply find an example and blindly copy it.  Each JSON source is different and you must understand the structure to know how to pick it apart.  *Understand* what you're doing and things will go a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the `AFNetworking` framework 
you can donwload it [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Here is the documentation about the JSON requests : 
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.2/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html

You can also have a look [here](http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/) for an example of how to use it.

Comment: There is much to recommend this framework, although it is a bit "challenging" for a newbie, at least in the forms I've seen used.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON posts in my app I use SBJson. This method uses an NSURLConnection along with a HTTP Post request. The return data, when parsed, will come in the form of keys and strings in an NSDictionary. (jsonData is an NSDictionary established somewhere elese) (Apparently NSJSONSerialization does the same thing though)

```
(void) doJson:(NSString *)post {

CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1, FALSE);

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"youraddress"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
jsonData = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];

NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
```

Comment: I cant see how just giving him the code helps here. Please explain how do you think this answer will help him understand JSON parsing and ways to save it and use it in future.

Comment: He asked what the best class is, so I said I use SBJSon and this is how I do it. He also asks what the best way to store and view the returned data, my code also shows that.

Comment: Ill put some more description in with my code :)

Comment: But it does not state why do you think SBJSOn is better than JSONKit or NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: I dont know if SBJson is better than NSJSONSerialization. I have been told NSJSONSerialization does the same thing, hence 'apparently', but I made no claims about performance as I havent used the latter two.

Comment: Yeah and I will upvote your answer then. Frankly NSJSonSerialization is an internal class so it should be preferred. Also, JSONKIT is a good external library and it has very good performance as you can see here:http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/

Comment: I had originally used SBJSon (maybe NSJSonSerialization just wasnt bought to my attention) and it worked and works pretty well (I have really limited use of it), so left it.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin way to serilize a json is [NSSerilization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Is used as:

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; //  json data
```

Deserialize as:

```
NSArray *arrayOfJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response
options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

But it should be known that what format json is returning. That can be NSArray or NSDictionary.

Getting data from JSON

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrayOfJson count];i++)
{
    arr= [arrayOfJson objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@”Json value: %@”, [arr objectForKey:@"youJSONKey"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to retrieve the JSON data depends on your use case, therefore, I can not help you with that.

Parsing JSON is very straight forward in iOS. You just convert the JSON Data to a NSArray or NSDictionary (depending on the root element of your JSON data) with the [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Example downloading and parsing JSON (with an array as base object) from a web service:

The JSON is supposed to have a format similar to `["1","2","last"]` in this example.

in the .h:

```
@interface WSHandler : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}

- (void)callWebService;
@end
```

in the .m:

```
#import "WSHandler.h"

@implementation WSHandler
- (void)callWebService
{   

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:/* here goes your WS URL*/]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection)
    {
        receivedData = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be established");
    }
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection delegate methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (!receivedData)
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
    else
        [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"***** Connection failed");

    receivedData=nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data
    NSLog(@"***** Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    NSLog(@"***** AS UTF8:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    //JSON parsing
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *receivedDataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    if (receivedDataArray==nil || receivedDataArray.count<=0 || err)
    {
        DLog(@"***** Error! %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        //logs each element of the array
        for (int i=0;i<receivedDataArray.count;i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Element %i = %@",i,[receivedDataArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        }       
    }    
}
@end
```